# Request in symfony return me some weird data

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I wanted to get data from a bdd, like I always do I create a method for add specific condition to my request, but you'll see after I tried many things else.

Here the request:

```
    /**
     * @return CongesEchangeRtt[] Returns an array of CongesEchangeRtt objects
     */
    public function findByDate($agents, $date) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->andWhere('c.eLogin IN (:val)')
            ->andWhere('c.eDateJour LIKE :date')
            ->setParameter('val', $agents)
            ->setParameter('date', $date . "%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

This request had to return me every data that match with condition, right?
But we're wrong, lol, IDK why but this is not what it do, in fact I tried it, in pur SQL, in "phpMyAdmin" and it worked so I think that my problem come from symfony, anyway this request return me only one object per user (agents). Datas I get are correct, but I don't get *every* data that match for each user... I lost my mind here in first, but it's only the beginning.

After that I tried a simple "findBy" method with the user array in parameter, I got every date of every user in my array, but it's to mutch, I want to get only thoses with the correct dates, I mean those who are in the 'actual' month that I display in the front, 'actual' is relative.
So I generate an array with every date of the month and tried this:

```
findBy(["login" => $myUserArray, "dates" => $myArrayOfDates]);
```

You now what I got? Something weird! Right!
Duplicate content... But some that are not in the bdd, I mean, here an example:

I have many data/lines in this table that look like this:

```
login|date(vacation)|presence|absence|comment
```

so:

```
"xxxx.xxxx"|"2021-05-14"|etc
"xxxx.xxxxx"|"2021-05-24"|etc
```

And I got this in my PHP:

```
"xxxx.xxxx"|"2021-05-14"|etc
"xxxx.xxxx"|"2021-05-14"|etc
```

I have the right number of data, but they're all the same...

Comment: Using LIKE in date columns is somewhat unusual.  Typically you would use date specific sql functions which in doctrine may or may not require a bit of customization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was looking for information on what you were talking about, to find out, and I thank you for this advice, only the problem is not that I use a LIKE on dates, but above all that the return of the request gives me completely aberrant data, i need explication

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the difference between my entity and the Table in the bdd.
'Cause this is a part of an old system, and idk why but the dev how code it add two PRIMARY KEY to this table, and when I generate my entity with symfony he didn't created it as the table was. he forgot one PRIMARY KEY, maybe beaucause it's a special case, normaly i read that a table only need one PRIMARY KEY, anyway, i fixed it by adding the right annotation to my paramater that represent the field in the database that was the second PRIMARY KEY, after that the problem was solved.

I change this :

```
    /**
     * @var \Datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="e_date_jour", type="date", nullable=false, options={"default"="0000-00-00"})
     */
    private $eDateJour = '0000-00-00';
```

To this :

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="e_date_jour", type="string", nullable=false, options={"default"="0000-00-00"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $eDateJour = '0000-00-00';
```

I change the get and set fonction too, 'cause symfony specified the return's type by himself when you generate the entity, it's a good practice btw.